# onPress & onLongPress in navigationOptions for TabNavigator (React Navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

i want to handle onPress for each tab so i decided to add this to each page:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  header: null,
  tabBarVisible: true,
  onPress: ({}) => alert("it's a tap!")
  onLongPress : ({}) => alert("it's a Long Press!")
};
```

but it's not working!
i searched in issues and see complicated codes! i just want to show an alert or navigate to another screeen!

i **didn't** use Icon and i have text in my tabs so i can't use icon's onPress!

also, i **didn't** use TabBarBottom or Redux

> thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#navigationoptions-used-by-tabnavigator) to the `react-navigation's` `tabNavigator`, and it supports only [tabBarOnPress](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress), still unclear what `alert` is used for.

Comment: alert is an example! so i can't have onPress for each tab...
tnx :)

Comment: You might need [Alert](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html)

Comment: i can't hande onPress! i don't have problem with alert!